# Definite Integral $\int_0^r\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}{R^2}\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am calculating the area of a circle (radius r) inscribed over a cylindrical surface (radius R).

Projection of circle or radius r on cylinder of radius R.

How do I solve the following integral?

$$\int_0^r\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}{R^2}\right)dx$$

Comment: Start with integration by parts.

Comment: I have the bad feeling that this would lead to some elliptic integrals.

Comment: Something is wrong in your formula. Are you sure this is $R^2$ and not $R$ in the denominator ? A dimensional analysis shows also that your integral is a length, not an area.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach. Recalling the power series of $\arcsin x$, we have

> $$ I = \sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac { \left( 2\,k \right) !\,{4}^{-k}}{ \left( k! \right) ^{2} \left( 2\,k+1 \right) }}
> \int_{0}^{r}( r^2-x^2 )^{(2k+1)/2} \,dx .$$

Now, use the substitution $u=x/r$ and use the [beta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) function to evaluate the integral, then resum the resulting series which will give you the answer in terms of [Elliptic integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral)

> $$ \frac{r^2}{R^2} K\left( {\frac {r}{{R}^{2}}} \right) -{R
> }^{2}{K} \left( {\frac {r}{{R}^{2}}} \right) +{R}^{2}{E} \left( {\frac {r}{{R}^{2}}} \right) 
> .$$

You can use computer algebra systems to sum the resulting series.

**Note:** Double check my calculations.

Comment: i am not from mathematical background. even never heard of 'Elliptic integrals'!!! seems i need to lot of study. thanks a lot to all.

Comment: @user123910: This is not an elementary integral, so do not expect to have a closed form in terms of ordinary functions.